# Database of system messages translations?

Tags: windows, translation, windows-error-reporting

Often I am trying find about error messages, occurring in Russian version of Windows. They are in Russian and my own translation into English gives not exact spelling, making it impossible to find the resolution.

Is there any online translation database, containing information about how various messages were translated into various languages?